# Code in C# that creates redirect buttons in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a C# string builder that will later build an html page based on information in a database and user input.

What I am having trouble with is creating two buttons in the string where one button redirects to page a.asp and the other button redirects to b.asp

I have tried multiple methods but none seem to work. Here is my latest version of code but I might be way off track:

in my page.asp.cs file:

```
responseString +=
                "<div>"
                +"<table><tr>"
                +"<td><button id='submitSave' type='submit'>Save</button></td>"
                + "<td><button id='continueBatch' onserverclick=\"OnClickButton\" type='submit' runat'server'>Continue Batch</button></td>"
                + "<td><button id='submitDelete' onclick='confirmDialog()' type='button'>Delete</button></td>"
                + "</tr></table></div>";
```

and it points to the method also in page.asp.cs:

```
public void OnClickButton()
{
    //Redirect to New 
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("New.aspx?fmtypeP={0}&formverP={1}", FormTypeS, FormVersionS));
}
```

and last but not least I have in the page.asp page the following:

```
<form action="save.aspx" method="POST">
```

I know the form action will need to change but I just wanted to let you know I currently had it in place.

Am I working in the right direction? Is there an easier way to accomplish my task? If not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using asp.net-mvc? If so, why not using Razor?

Comment: I am trying to update a page that was made by another coder a while ago.

Comment: I would say first find out what technology you are using (Webforms or MVC) and then ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rely on ajax to solve this problem if possible. One solution would be to use onclick and call an existing javascript method like you seem to have done for the confirmDialog() on the delete button. Maybe use jquery's wrapper for the ajax call: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Let the server method return the redirect link and use window.location = the return value in the success-method.

Or if you know what the redirect links should be when building the string you can make the redirect directly: onclick='window.location = "your redirect link"'

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can not use server-side controls like that. In your code they just added to response stream and not being compile and stuff. You need to add controls to your aspx page or add them in code like actual controls via new(), not like strings.